# An artistic trip

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Here are 6 places I visited in 2008:

[image]

Now tell me, **where was the Sun?**

Comment: Rot13 Jryy, gur fha jnf boivbhfyl va fcnpr... but somehow I don't think that that is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Joe Keer Indeed :p

Comment: If you had travelled to those same places in 2020, would the answer be different?

Comment: @TTT The date is a small clue, merely confirming the relationship of the places ; the answer would not be different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the places in the map are

> close to famous battles (from WWI and WWII) that are referenced in songs in "[The Art of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_War_(Sabaton_album))" album published by Sabaton in 2008, hence the "artistic" part in the title.

- France:

> Not sure what's the specific place marked, but it was part of the Battle of France, referenced in the second song, "Ghost Division".

- Poland:

> the Battle of Wizna, referenced in the fourth song, "40:1".

- Southern Italy:

> the Gallipoli Campaign, referenced in the seventh song,  "Cliffs of Gallipoli".

- Russia:

> the Battle of Kursk, referenced in the ninth song, "Panzerkampf".

- Northern Italy:

> the Battle of Monte Cassino, referenced in the tenth song, "Union (Slopes of St. Benedict)".

- Belgium:

> the Battle of Passchendaele, referenced in the eleventh song, "The Price of a Mile".

To answer the question, take into account that:

> The album also contains songs with quotes from Sun Tzu's "The Art of War". Considering this, I'd say the answer is:
> **(the) Sun (Tzu) was in China**

Comment: Well done! For the French one, I decided to put Avesnes, which was the initial (but largely exceeded) objective of the 7th Panzer Division.
Also, I took the liberty to add spoiler tags to your answer ;)

Comment: Oh, right, I keep forgetting to spoilertag the content :P Nice question!